# How to catch RuntimeException

Tags: android, try-catch

In my app i need to handle large bitmaps.Once i load my bitmap i want to show it in my imageview

```
                        try {
                            bitmap = GlideBitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);                              
                        } catch (OutOfMemoryError) {
                           //i do stuff in order to load bitmap                  
                        }
```

My problem is that i can't catch `java.lang.RuntimeException` using the following try catch.

```
                            try {
                               ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImageView);

                               i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                               //never came here                 
                            }
```

Logcat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(116640000bytes) bitmap.
            at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
            at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
            at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:528)
            at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1316)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17214)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16196)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1366)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17217)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16196)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16191)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16980)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3729)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3515)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17217)
            at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:757)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16196)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2837)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2645)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2252)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6396)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:876)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:688)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:623)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:862)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

i know that `Exception` should catch `RuntimeException`. So what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because of this.

When you call `setImageBitmap()`, Android converts that bitmap to a Drawable and then internally calls `setImageDrawable()`.

`setImageDrawable()` basically just updates a global variable (`mDrawable`) and then invalidates the ImageView. That means that you're no longer directly connected to the process of setting the image, as it seems to go through a Handler call, so you can no longer catch any Exception that's thrown.

You really should just scale the Bitmap before you set it instead of relying on the fact that it will throw an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not `catching exception` that is thrown by this code. `GlideBitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath)`. It's throwing `runtime exception`. Suggestion replace `OutOfMemoryError` with `runtime exception`. Use `decodeFile(photoPath, 100, 100)` to downsample the bitmap where second and third parameters are required `width` and `height`.

Comment: i want to keep high quality of my image. My problem is to handle large bitmaps. So the question is: How can i catch throwIfCannotDraw when i call setImageBitmap()